# How to have a single search panel including all searching options in Intellij IDE?

Tags: intellij-idea, configuration

I need to know how to open the search panel that includes all the 
different searching options (All, classes, Files ..) like this:

https://www.google.com/search?q=intellij+search+classes&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwikhb793urfAhVHyhoKHeiPBDUQ_AUIDygC&biw=1745&bih=860#imgrc=SGrlYMJQfuMQuM:

I can open the filter for each kind of search separately, but not on the same panel. I'm using the community edition and I was wondering if this is a intelliJ Ultimate specific feature.

Thank you for your help

Comment: I think double shift (hit shift key twice) is what you're looking for

Comment: Yes it works, but was necessary to update to the last version

Answer (score 0):

You should be updated to the last version of IntelliJ IDEA and search for one of the options (`all` (double shift), `classes`, etc.)